# Building a massive query based on single query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I use `"mysql": "^2.18.1"` on NodeJs.

I have a query that resembles
`` updateProperty: `UPDATE object SET property = ? WHERE id = ?;` ``
. In code I have a lot of objects of each I want to update the property each `x seconds` so I thought I would just concat the query like:

```
let query = "";
let args = [];
for(const obj of objects){
    query += updateProperty;
    args.push(obj.property);
    args.push(obj.id);
}
```

and then use `DB.query(query, args, (err: any) => { ... })`
but I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version` in this case.

I also tried replacing in the query directly with `replace("?", obj.property)` etc but encounter the same error.

Is there a "better" way to approach this?

Comment: Not sure if the '?' method works for multi-query, but I'm guessing you're just missing the ';' in your query string between each update query? Ex. `UPDATE x WHERE id = ?; UPDATE y WHER id = ?;`

Comment: i was missing `multipleStatements: true` in the createConnection :/ thank you all!

Comment: Requiring a regular interval update of a property looks wrong. Consider if there's a way to keep the way it is fixed and query it based on the current time. e.g. store the expire date/time and not the hours/minutes/seconds remaining.